# "Point on Circle" base on given angle

Tags: python, python-2.7, trigonometry

okay, i have a circle and i want get the point on circle in 90 degree of origin.

```
def point_on_circle():
    '''
        Finding the x,y coordinates on circle, based on given angle
    '''
    from math import cos, sin
    #center of circle, angle in degree and radius of circle
    center = [0,0]
    angle = 90
    radius = 100
    #x = offsetX + radius * Cosine(Degree)
    x = center[0] + (radius * cos(angle))
    #y = offsetY + radius * Sine(Degree)
    y = center[1] + (radius * sin(angle))

    return x,y

>>> print point_on_circle()
[-44.8073616129 , 89.3996663601]
```

since pi start from 3 o'clock, i expected to get `x=0` and `y=100`but i have no idea why i'm getting that.

what am i doing wrong?

**Edit:** even i convert to radians, still i get weird result.

```
def point_on_circle():
    '''
        Finding the x,y coordinates on circle, based on given angle
    '''
    from math import cos, sin, radians
    #center of circle, angle in degree and radius of circle
    center = [0,0]
    angle = radians(90)
    radius = 100
    #x = offsetX + radius * Cosine(radians)
    x = center[0] + (radius * cos(angle))
    #y = offsetY + radius * Sine(radians)
    y = center[1] + (radius * sin(angle))

    return x,y

>>> print point_on_circle()
[6.12323399574e-15 , 100.0]
```

any idea how to get accurate number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`math.cos` and `math.sin` expect radians, not degrees. Simply replace `90` by `pi/2`:

```
def point_on_circle():
    '''
        Finding the x,y coordinates on circle, based on given angle
    '''
    from math import cos, sin, pi
    #center of circle, angle in degree and radius of circle
    center = [0,0]
    angle = pi / 2
    radius = 100
    x = center[0] + (radius * cos(angle))
    y = center[1] + (radius * sin(angle))

    return x,y
```

You'll get `(6.123233995736766e-15, 100.0)` which is close to `(0, 100)`.

If you want better precision, you can [try SymPy online](http://live.sympy.org/) before installing it yourself:

```
>>> from sympy import pi, mpmath
>>> mpmath.cos(pi/2)
6.12323399573677e−17
```

We're getting closer, but this is still using floating-point. However, mpmath.cospi gets you the correct result:

```
>>> mpmath.cospi(1/2)
0.0
```

Comment: yeah, i've try that, and i get `[6.12323399574e-15 , 100.0]`

Comment: @Bear Did it occur to you that `6.12323399574e-15` is a _tiny_ number?

Comment: @Bear You need to learn more about floating-point arithmetic: since "pi/2" is not the real, symbolic pi/2 but an approximation and cos() is just an approximation, you won't get 0, but something close to 0, eg. 6*10^-15.

Comment: well, it does matter for me, cause it will effect the whole program calculation, how can i get accurate number then?

Comment: @Bear I've added a SimPy version, but you should also learn to embrace floating point arithmetic. Errors do compound, but you can learn how to 1/ mitigate this 2/ accept answers that are close enough.

Comment: i see... if i round it i will get 6 which is not really close, but `mpmath.cospi()` is working fine, thanks, also before i accept your answer, do you have any idea how `mpmath.cospi()` work mathematically?

Comment: @Bear 6.12323399574e-15 is the [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) for  0.00000000000000612323399574. Closer to 0 than to 6. :) SimPy can operate on symbols, so it could know that cos(pi/2) is 0. I don't know about the specifics of cospi() though.

Comment: oh yeah, you are right! i didn't see the "e-15" :D, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The sin() & cos() expect radians use:

```
x = center[0] + (radius * cos(angle*pi/180));
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things need to be changed.

- First, you need to change `range = 90` to `range = radians(90)` which means you need to import radians.
- Second you need to subtract the range from radian(360) so you get it starting in quadrant I instead of quadrant IV. Once you are done, your should have changed `range = 90` to `range = radians(360 - 90)` and have imported radians.

Then if you want to stop your answer from having floating-point, you have `return int(x), int(y)` instead of `return x,y` at the end of your function. I made these changes and it worked.